# Calculus - Prove that $\{a_n\}$ converges

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to prove that $a_n$ converges :

$$a_n=\frac{1}{2+1}+\frac{1}{2^2+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n+n}$$

**My solution**

Let choose $\epsilon=1$, Exist $N>0$ so all $N \leq x$ appiles $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$

Therefore :

$$\left|\frac{1}{2^n+n}-L\right|<\epsilon=1$$
$$L-1<\frac{1}{2^n+n}<L+1$$

Therefore the function is bounded.

Also $a_n$ is increasing since $a_{n+1}-a_n>0$

$$a_n = \frac{1}{2^n+n}$$
$$a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2^{(n+1)}+n+1}$$

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{1}{2^n+n}-\frac{1}{2^{(n+1)}+n+1}=\frac{2^{n+1}+n+1-2^n-n}{(2^n+n)(2^{n+1}+n+1)}=\frac{2^{n+1}+1-2^n}{(2^n+n)(2^{n+1}+n+1)}>0 (1 \leq n)$$

As well it clear that the function is continuous since $1,2^n,n$ are continuous.

Therefore it possible to conclude that the function is converges.

Is this proof perfect?

Thanks!

Comment: $\frac{1}{2^n +n} < \frac{1}{2^n}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is equivalent to establishing the convergence of the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n+n},
$$
and perhaps the easiest way to do this is using the [Comparison Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test), i.e., observe that
$$
\frac{1}{2^n+n}<\frac{1}{2^n},
$$
and use the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}<\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Notice that $$\frac{1}{2^n+n} < \frac{1}{2^n}$$

And use the [Comparison Test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0tXxFPHzFFI).

Comment: This is what I instantly thought when I saw this. You got it before I could. $+1$